# Querying $request result before storing data in Controllers with "POST" method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, response

Firstly, I'm sorry because I am new in Laravel. I want to do query/eloquent with `$request->id_anggota` as result from `"POST"` method, so that I can get `email` properties from another table and insert `email` value to `alokasikegiatan` table. Please help!

My code:

```php
public function getEmail($request)
{
    $em = '';
    //code...
    $row_peg = DB::table('users')->where('nip', $request->id_anggota)->first()->email;
    if (count($row_peg) > 0) {
        $em = $row_peg;
    } else {
        $em = DB::table('registeredmitra')->where('sobatid', $request->id_anggota)->first()->email;
    };
    return $em;
}
```

I want to pass that code before querying this one

```php
public function store_alok(Request $request)
{
    try {
        AlokasiKegiatan::insert([
            'id_keg' => $request->id_keg,
            'email' => $this->getEmail($request),
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    };
}
```

As you can see i call this:

> 'email' => $this->getEmail($request),

But I got this error

> Trying to get property 'email' of non-object

Is there another possible way to do that? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access a record even if it doesn't exist, both times in your getEmail function. Move the `->email` inside of the first `if` clause and add another for the second, to make sure the record exists before you try to access it.

```
public function getEmail($request)
{
    $em = '';
    //code...
    $row_peg = DB::table('users')->where('nip', $request->id_anggota)->first();
    if ($row_peg) {
        $em = $row_peg->email;
    } else {
        $row = DB::table('registeredmitra')->where('sobatid', $request->id_anggota)->first();
        if($row) {
            $em = $row->email;
        }
    };
    return $em;
}
```